# Flask project always got error "We're sorry, but something went wrong"

Tags: python, flask

I'm a beginner in Flask and I have developed a face-detection application based on it. I had many problems when deploy project on a cPanel host and can solve that one by one. But now have another problem that always say me **We're sorry, but something went wrong** and I do not know what is problem because has no error in log file.

I have a python_files directory included three files like **app.py** , **passenger_wsgi.py** and **prediction_blueprint.py** and following are the things that are inside.

**app.py** file :

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from prediction_blueprint import prediction_blueprint

# from time import sleep

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates', static_folder='../static')
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True

app.register_blueprint(prediction_blueprint)


@app.route('/')
def index():  # put application's code here
    return render_template('./index.html')


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    fn = secure_filename(file.filename)
    # sleep(3)
    file.save(os.path.join('../uploads', fn))
    return {
        "success": True,
        "message": fn
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**passenger_wsgi.py** file:

```
import imp
import os
import sys


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'app.py')

application = wsgi.app
```

and **prediction_blueprint.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, Flask, request
from keras_vggface import VGGFace, utils
from keras_vggface.utils import preprocess_input
from mtcnn import MTCNN
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import json, requests

prediction_blueprint = Blueprint('prediction_blueprint', __name__)

vggface = VGGFace(model='vgg16')
detector_obj = MTCNN()


@prediction_blueprint.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    image = request.get_json().get('image')

    face = extract_face('../uploads/' + image).astype('float32')
    input_sample = np.expand_dims(face, axis=0)
    samples = preprocess_input(input_sample)

    pred = vggface.predict(samples)

    output = utils.decode_predictions(pred)

    founded_person = output[0][0][0].replace("b'", "").replace("'", "")

    result = {
        "success": True,
        "message": {}
    }

    if founded_person:
        celeb_name = get_best_title_wiki_page(founded_person)

        if celeb_name:
            result['message']['celeb_name'] = celeb_name

            celeb_images = get_celeb_images(celeb_name)

            if celeb_images:
                result['message']['celeb_images'] = celeb_images

            return result
        else:
            return {
                "success": False,
                "message": "Best Title Not Found!"
            }

    else:
        return {
            "success": False,
            "message": "Not Found any things !",
        }


def extract_face(address):
    img = cv.imread(address)

    rgb_img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    face = detector_obj.detect_faces(rgb_img)[0]
    x, y, w, h = face['box']

    actual_face = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]  # This crop only section of image that contain person Face
    actual_face = cv.resize(actual_face, (224, 224))

    return np.asarray(actual_face)


def get_best_title_wiki_page(celeb_name):
    endpoint = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
    parameters = {
        "action": "query",
        "list": "search",
        "srsearch": celeb_name,
        "format": "json",
        "origin": "*"
    }

    best_title = None

    try:
        response = requests.get(endpoint, params=parameters)
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        best_title = data["query"]["search"][0]["title"]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return best_title


def get_celeb_images(celeb_name):
    endpoint = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
    parameters = {
        "action": "query",
        "titles": celeb_name,
        "prop": "images",
        "iiprop": "url",
        "format": "json",
        "origin": "*"
    }

    try:
        response = requests.get(endpoint, params=parameters)
        data = json.loads(response.text)

        page_id = list(data["query"]["pages"].keys())[0]
        images = data["query"]["pages"][page_id]["images"]

        filtered_images = [image for image in images if
                           "file:" + celeb_name.lower() in image[
                               "title"].lower() or "file:" + celeb_name.lower().replace(" ", "") in image[
                               "title"].lower()]

        image_urls = [f"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Redirect/file/{image['title'].replace('File:', '')}" for
                      image in filtered_images]

        cel_images = image_urls[0:4]

        return cel_images

    except Exception as e:
        print("Getting Images API request Failed", e)
```

these are all things that I have wrote , all packages are installed properly But I so not know which problem caused **We're sorry, but something went wrong** message?

Of course, I have a warning like this in log.log file while I think it cannot cause the problem :

```
App 631448 output: /opt/passenger-5.3.7-13.el7.cloudlinux/src/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py:26: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
App 631448 output:   import sys, os, io, re, imp, threading, signal, traceback, socket, select, struct, logging, errno
```

Answer (score 2):

in your **passenger_wsgi.py** file:

replace:

`import imp` -> `from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader`

and

`imp.load_source('wsgi', 'app.py')` -> `SourceFileLoader('wsgi', 'app.py').load_module()`

`imp` won't exist anymore in newer python versions (3.12?) and can be replaced by `importlib`. But they warn you about it already beforehand that's why you get an error warning.

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
import os
import sys


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
wsgi = SourceFileLoader('wsgi', 'app.py').load_module()

application = wsgi.app
```

Comment: I changed `passenger_wsgi.py` But I got same error again. error says that in `helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py` some things should be change

Comment: Have you got the solution @Ahmad ? If yes, please share.

Comment: @MurariMahaseth, Unfortunately, no I could not find the problem yet.